# Getting different outputs on different terminals for identical python program

Tags: python, linux, terminal, python-tesseract

The goal of my program is to use Tesseract for OCR and extract the gender demographics from  an image. When the program is executed it loops through the images in the folder and writes the output into a file. The output of the function is a dictionary containing the male, female, third and total count from the image.

```
def countPeople(img):
    cropped = img
    stats = detect_box(cropped)
    # cropped = cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # (_, cropped) = cv2.threshold(cropped, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    bigtext = ""    
    for stat in stats[2:]:
        if stat[4] > 40000 and stat[4] < 100000:
            x1 = stat[0]
            x2 = stat[0] + stat[2]
            y1 = stat[1]
            y2 = stat[1] + stat[3]
            crop = cropped[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            crop = Image.fromarray(crop)
            text = tc.image_to_text(crop)
            bigtext += text.strip() + "\n"

    pattern = r"(\d+)"    
    lines = bigtext.split("\n")
    male = -1
    female = -1
    third = -1
    total = -1
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        x = re.search(pattern, lines[i])
        if x:
            male = (x.group(1))
            female = (lines[i + 1].strip())
            if len(lines[i + 2].strip()) != 0:
                third = (lines[i + 2].strip())
            else:
                third = 0
            total = (lines[i + 3].strip())
            break
    demo = dict()
    demo['male'] = male
    demo['female'] = female
    demo['other'] = third
    demo['total'] = total
    return demo
```

However, when I run this identical function on two different terminals, I am getting two different outputs.

[image: output of the terminals]

I checked to ensure they ran on the same version of python as well (Python 3.6.9). It is an identical function running on identical inputs that are providing two different outputs.

Comment: And what about the versions of tesseract and all underlying libraries?

Comment: They are all identical. Running the same exact program on a different terminal is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: So ... this is two terminals on the same machine? Same directories? What happens if you  re-run it within each of the terminals? Same results each time or different ones?

Comment: Yes, same machine, same directories, same everything. If I rerun the program within the terminals the outputs don't change from before. The difference is between the two terminals itself.